# Can Jsf prevent clickjacking attack ?

Tags: jsf, clickjacking

> Can **JSF** prevent clickjacking attack ? If not, how to prevent it.

Comment: Click jacking is a purely client-side problem. JSF is in this regard merely an html generator. So prevention of clickjacking should solved in a similar way as with pure html.

Comment: You means JSF not prevent clickjacking.So, how to prevent it.

Comment: There are more than one 'related' questions on the right. Google is your friend.

Comment: Clickjacking is only possible if website has a XSS hole somewhere which is in turn utilized to inject such an iframe. But if website already doesn't have a XSS hole in first place, then clickjacking isn't possible at all. You can always add the documented response headers yourself if you want.